# Getting started with java and OAuth - should we use code.google.com/p/oauth?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth

Trying to get started with OAuth - I have a webapp using google app engine (java). I'd like to let users find friends via twitter, gmail, yahoo, etc etc. For this I believe I need to get them to authorize my app, then I can use each api to search their friends/contacts etc.

I believe I'm supposed to copy all the contents of the:

```
net.oauth
```

package from here:

```
http://code.google.com/p/oauth/
```

into my own project, then I think I can get started. There's no jar of the project, so I guess we just import the java files oursevles?

Just wondering if there's another method to getting started, like is there some official OAuth library or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok found something that works:
http://code.google.com/p/dyuproject

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple libraries, but what seems like a good choices is SignPost, http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/, since I like its focus on doing one thing right. Other libraries work ok too.